# Procedure for entry with the name of the declared operations

Tags: c

I coded an AVL Tree and now I am trying to code a service for users of the program.

Here is my problem:

Input: n - number of operations 
This is easy, I will create a for loop `(i = 0; i < n; i++)`, i will be incremented after operation.

But I dont know how I can code entry with the namne of the declared operation.

List of operations:

- insert x - insert x to AVL Tree
- delete x - delete x from AVL Tree
- min - print min element
- max - print max element

Struct of Tree:

```
entestruct avl_tree {
int key;
int bf;
struct avl_tree *up;
struct avl_tree *left;
struct avl_tree *right;
};

typedef struct avl_tree node;
```

I coded the insert function like:

```
void insert(node **tree, int k){ ... }
```

I know how I can add value to tree: `insert(&root, k)`, but I dont know how I can take a one line from user with the name of operation and value and what I should do when operation dont need a value like operation min or max.

Example how program should work:

Input:

```
4 // [this is n - number of operations]    
insert 1 // [insert(&root, k)]    
insert 3 // [insert(&root, k]    
max // [max(k)]    
min // [min(k)]
```

Output:

```
3
1
```

Comment: Written code so far? Better explanation? Please edit you post with that...

Comment: Ok i edited this. It should be better now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i wrote some code:

```
char str[100];
int n, x, i;

scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = 0; i<=n; i++){

    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    if (!strncmp(str, "insert", 6)) {
        sscanf(str,"%*[^0-9]%d", &x);
        insert(&root, x);
        str[0] = '\0';          
    }


    if (!strncmp(str, "delete", 6)) {
        sscanf(str,"%*[^0-9]%d", &x);
        delete(&root, x);
        str[0] = '\0';              
    }


    if (!strncmp(str, "max", 3)) {
        max(&root);
        str[0] = '\0';          
    }

    if (!strncmp(str, "min", 3)) {
        min(&root);
        str[0] = '\0';      
    }
}
```

Its good solution?

Edit:

Ok its working. Here is full code of main with some new operations:

```
node *root;
root = NULL;
node *tmp;
tmp = NULL;

char str[100];
int n, x, i;

scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = 0; i<=n; i++){
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    if (!strncmp(str, "insert", 6)) {
        sscanf(str,"%*[^0-9]%d", &x);
        insert(&root, x);
        str[0] = '\0';          
    }

    if (!strncmp(str, "delete", 6)) {
        sscanf(str,"%*[^0-9]%d", &x);
        tmp = find(root, x);
        if(tmp) removeAVL(&root, tmp);  
        str[0] = '\0';              
    }

    if(!strncmp(str, "find", 4)) {
        sscanf(str,"%*[^0-9]%d", &x);
        tmp = find(root, x);
        if(tmp) printf("%d\n", 1);
        else printf("%d\n", 0);
        str[0] = '\0';
    }

    if(!strncmp(str, "inorder", 7)) { 
        if(root) print_inorder(root);         
        else printf(" ");
        printf("\n");
        str[0] = '\0';      
    }     

    if (!strncmp(str, "max", 3)) {
        if(root) max(root);
        else printf(" \n");
        str[0] = '\0';          
    }

    if (!strncmp(str, "min", 3)) {
        if(root) min(root);
        else printf(" \n");
        str[0] = '\0';      
    }
                            }   

return 0;
```